# COCOS2D - Removing a child if it collides with another sprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am working on a game that has the player controlling a spaceShip. I want to make it such that if the spaceShip sprite collides with spaceJunk the junk disappears.

Here is my code so far.

HelloWorldLayer.h

```
 #import <GameKit/GameKit.h>


   // HelloWorldLayer
   @interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayerColor
{
CCSprite *_starShip;
CCSprite *_Paddle1;
CCSprite *_paddle2;

}

// returns a CCScene that contains the HelloWorldLayer as the only child
+(CCScene *) scene;

@end
```

HelloWorldLayer.M

```
// Import the interfaces
#import "HelloWorldLayer.h"

// Needed to obtain the Navigation Controller
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#pragma mark - HelloWorldLayer

// HelloWorldLayer implementation

//Import SpaceThings

#import "SpaceThings.h"

@implementation HelloWorldLayer{

}


// Helper class method that creates a Scene with the HelloWorldLayer as the only child.
+(CCScene *) scene
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    HelloWorldLayer *layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}

-(void)gameLgoic:(ccTime)dt
{
    [self addSpaceThings];
}


-(void) addSpaceThings
{
   // _junk = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"catplaceholder.png"];

    SpaceThings * spaceThings = nil;

    if (arc4random() % 2 == 0){
        spaceThings = [[[Astroids alloc] init] autorelease];
    }else{
        spaceThings = [[[SpaceJunk alloc]init] autorelease];

    }

    //determine where to spawn the space junk along the X-axis
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    int minX = spaceThings.contentSize.width/2;
    int maxX = winSize.width - spaceThings.contentSize.width/2;
    int rangeX =maxX - minX;
    int actualX = (arc4random() % rangeX) + minX;


    //spawn the sprite slightly above the screen
    spaceThings.position = ccp(actualX, winSize.height+_starShip.contentSize.height/2);
    [self addChild:spaceThings];

    //set the speed of junk
    int minDuration = spaceThings.minMoveDirection;
    int maxDuarton = spaceThings.maxMoveDirection;
    int rangeDuration = maxDuarton - minDuration;
    float actualDuraton = (arc4random() % rangeDuration)+ minDuration;

    //move junk logic
    CCMoveTo * actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuraton position:ccp(actualX, -spaceThings.contentSize.height/2)];
    CCCallBlockN *actionMoveDone = [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode *node){[node removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];}];
    [spaceThings runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(_starShip.boundingBox, spaceThings.boundingBox)){
        [self removeChild:spaceThings cleanup:YES];

    }




}

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
-(id) init
{
    if (self =[super initWithColor:ccc4(255,255,255,255)]){
        CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
        _starShip = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"theShip.gif"];
        _starShip.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, 1.25*_starShip.contentSize.height);
        //make the starship appear
        [self addChild:_starShip];

        //make the paddles
        //bottom left one
        _Paddle1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"spritePaddle.jpeg"];
        int bottomOfScreenX = 0 + _Paddle1.contentSize.width/2;
        int bottomOfScreenY = 0+_Paddle1.contentSize.height/2;
        _Paddle1.position = ccp(bottomOfScreenX,bottomOfScreenY);
        [self addChild:_Paddle1];
        //bottom right one
        _paddle2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"spritePaddle.jpeg"];
        int bottomRightOfScreenX = winSize.width - _paddle2.contentSize.width/2;
        _paddle2.position = ccp(bottomRightOfScreenX, bottomOfScreenY);
        [self addChild:_paddle2];


        //make thingsInSpace spawn at a set interval

        int setInterval = (arc4random() % 3);
        [self schedule:@selector(gameLgoic:) interval:setInterval];
        //enable touch
        [self setIsTouchEnabled:YES];



    }
    return self;
}

// on "dealloc" you need to release all your retained objects
- (void) dealloc
{
    // in case you have something to dealloc, do it in this method
    // in this particular example nothing needs to be released.
    // cocos2d will automatically release all the children (Label)

    // don't forget to call "super dealloc"
    [super dealloc];

}

-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //make the screens and create events
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [allTouches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    //check to see if the left paddle is being pressed
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([_Paddle1 boundingBox], location)){
         int bottomLeftOfScreenX = 0 + _Paddle1.contentSize.width/1.25;
        //make an action
        //the Y-coordinate of starShip must be the same since the ship must move parallel to it.
       id action = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2 position:ccp(bottomLeftOfScreenX,1.25*_starShip.contentSize.height) ];
        //have starship call this action
        [_starShip runAction:action];
        [action setTag:1];

    }
    //check to see if the right paddle is being pressed
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([_paddle2 boundingBox], location)){
        int bottomRightOfScreenX = winSize.width - _paddle2.contentSize.width/1.25;
        //make an action
        //the Y-coordinate of starShip must be the same since the ship moves parallel to it
        id action2 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2 position:ccp(bottomRightOfScreenX,1.25*_starShip.contentSize.height) ];
        //starShip is now running this specified action
        [_starShip runAction:action2];
        [action2 setTag:2];
    }


}

-(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   //if the player stops touching the pads, all the aciton should stop.

    //left button stop
    [_starShip stopActionByTag:1];
    //right button stop
    [_starShip stopActionByTag:2];

}

#pragma mark GameKit delegate

-(void) achievementViewControllerDidFinish:(GKAchievementViewController *)viewController
{
    AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[app navController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void) leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController
{
    AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[app navController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
@end
```

spaceThings.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface SpaceThings : CCSprite
@property (nonatomic, assign) int minMoveDirection;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int maxMoveDirection;

-(id)initWithFile:(NSString *)file minMoveDirection:(int)minMoveDirection maxMoveDirection:(int)maxMoveDirection;

@end

@interface Astroids : SpaceThings
@end

@interface SpaceJunk : SpaceThings
@end
```

SpaceThings.M

```
#import "SpaceThings.h"


@implementation SpaceThings

-(id)initWithFile:(NSString *)file minMoveDirection:(int)minMoveDirection maxMoveDirection:(int)maxMoveDirection
{
    if ((self =[super initWithFile:file])){
    self.minMoveDirection = minMoveDirection;
    self.maxMoveDirection = maxMoveDirection;
    }
    return self;
}

@end

@implementation Astroids

-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super initWithFile:@"astroid.jpeg" minMoveDirection:2 maxMoveDirection:5]){

    }
    return self;
}

@end

@implementation SpaceJunk
-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super initWithFile:@"blueDot.jpg" minMoveDirection:4 maxMoveDirection:7]){

    }
    return self;
}


@end
```

I'm wondering as to where to put CGRectInteresectRect part of the code. As I've currently tried placing within the SpaceJunk alloc init part and it doesn't remove the child when the ship collides with the junk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int setInterval = (arc4random() % 3);
    [self schedule:@selector(gameLgoic:) interval:setInterval];
```

Make setInterval value to float and give small value for schedular.

Also not do `[spaceThings runAction` inside loop. if required then do some condition check and run only if required.

Then your CGRectIntersectsRect will fire when intersect each other.

Happy Coding.

Comment: I tried out your suggestions and they didn't solve the problem. The sprites of space junk overlapping with the sprite of the spaceShip doesn't cause a removal of the particular spaceJunk child.

Comment: try [spaceThings removeFromParentAndCleanup:true];

Comment: Just tried the {[spaceThings removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];} and the problem still persists.

Comment: you are creating multiple instance of spaceThings in loop, if its not hit CGRectIntersectsRect then that object always in screen…good to keep NSMutable array and add all instance of spaceThings. I suggest you to take creation of object out side and store in array, remove when collision occurs and also remove from parent n from array. Ok, Happy Coding..learn to become expert !

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. Creating the array did solve the problem.